# Spring : Updating table entry

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am new to Web applications. I am implementing a simple one that enables to show all the entries of a table (i am using Spring + Hibernate). I added a column that contains a link enabling the update of a table entry (in reality, juste one column can be updated the other ones shouldn't be changed).

I would like that when i click on this **update link**, a form of update should be displayed
and this form is initialised with the values of the columns of the table entry.

for example: if the entry is :

USER1 | 55  | 190cm | 80kg  | "update link"

only the weight column can be updated, so the form of update so be **initialised** with:

*name* : USER1 (cannot be changed)
*age* : 55 (cannot be changed)
*height* : 190cm (cannot be changed)
*weight* : 80kg **( THE ONLY COLUMN THAT CAN BE CHANGED)**

How can i pass the values from the "display.jsp" page to the "update.jsp" page?
should i pass through the controller or froma jsp to jsp directly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Each controller must be responsible for loading appropriate data and passing them to corresponding view. The only info that you need to pass from one page to another is unique identifier of choosen line. Consider example where you want to change a record with unique identifier = 758. Normally unique identifier will be passed trough URL param:

http://example.com/update_controller_address?id=758

Comment: but this is to pas fro a jsp to a controller, i want to get all the values of the entry to display them in the update form.

Comment: But isn't the update form also backed by a controller? This controller is responsible for loading the data from the database and passing on this data to the jsp.

Comment: It is no a good idea to send all values from one page to another. Consider following example: user 1 and user 2 simultaneously display a list of items. Then user 2 changes line 1. If user 1 later will try to change the same line then he/she will see obsolete data. It will be better to prevent as musch of such kind of conflicts as possible. The most simple way is always reload data from database (during each page load).

Comment: In general what have you tried to do is some kind of cache. If you really need it then it will be better to use real cache, for example activate second level cache in hibernate.